# Xamarin vs. iOS / android

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, swift3

Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем технический, но интересно мнение. 
У меня сейчас около 8 лет разработки на С#. Начинал с winfoms, потом было немного wpf и сейчас около года уже Xamarin. И я понимаю, что мне это нравится. И вот вчера мне предложили начать изучать  swift или java чтобы писать для iOS или android, с определённым количеством аргументов в пользу нативной платформы. И прям подвис. Стоит или нет?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59359/discussion-on-question-by-atlantis-xamarin-vs-ios-android).